# How do I remove parts of a SVG that aren't on the page?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I downloaded this file from Wikimedia Commons ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnVz.png)) but there's a heap of the picture that doesn't fit on the document page and I'd like to know I can cut what doesn't fit on the page off so that it no longer appears in the SVG. Here is a screenshot illustrating what I mean. [image]

Comment: Are you meaning to export just the interesting [area](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/File-Export.html) or to [clip](http://inkscapetutorials.org/2014/04/22/inkscape-faq-how-do-i-crop-in-inkscape/#clipping) the image?

Comment: Clipping it would probably be the one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make a downloaded SVG fit the page in Inkscape we have two options:

#### 1. Clip the image to the page dimensions

- Import the SVG to a predefined page size

  [image]
- Draw a rectangle filling the whole page (or the area we want to clip out of the SVG):

  [image]
- Select both, the imported object(s), and the clipping rectangle
  (or choose *Edit > Select all* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
- Choose *Object > Clip > Set* to clip to the size of the rectangle

  [image]

Note that clipping will only define what parts of an object will be displayed but it will not remove the objects outside the clipped area. Any clipping can be undone by selecting *Object > Clip > Unset*.

#### 2. Adjust page size to the imported objects (or a selection)

- Choose *File > Document Properties* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- On the *Page Tab* open the *Resize page to content* and choose *Resize page to drawing or selection*

  [image]

Comment: Setting a clip appears to visually hide the objects but they are still present in the save file. This is both a risk of leaking unintended information and increases file size.